# Why do the masses of decay products affect the branching ratio?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, binding-energy

Consider a particle $P$ of mass $100m$ (where $m$ is some unit). It can decay into either of two particle-antiparticle pairs:

- $P\to P_1\bar{P}_1$ with branching ratio $BR_1$, where $P_1$ has mass $49m$
- $P\to P_2\bar{P}_2$ with branching ratio $BR_2$, where $P_2$ has mass $47m$

I read somewhere that the masses suggest that $BR_1 > BR_2$, and that this is implied by some concept involving "binding energies" in nuclear physics. However, I could not find anything about it on the internet.

Why would a decay product with mass closer to the mass of the decaying particle have a higher branching ratio?

Comment: Can you give a reference about the argument you invoke? I'd conclude the opposite: if $P_1$ and $P_2$ have the same properties with respect to the interaction responsible for the decay, the phase space available for the smaller mass is larger and thus the BR should be larger.

Comment: The key notion is the "phase space" mentioned by Paganini. And as he says it leads to larger cross-section for *lighter* decay products (all else being equal).

Comment: For example, consider $ \gamma (5S) $ (10876 MeV) . It can decay into $ B^*_s \bar{B^*_s}$ (10830 MeV),  $B_s \bar{B^*_s} $(10781 MeV) and $B_s \bar{B_s} $ (10732) .  The respective branching ratios are $ 17\%, 1\% and 5 \times 10^{-3}\%$. Can you justify these numbers using concept of Binding energy ?

Comment: @seeking_infinity Could edit your clarifying example (perhaps with a link to the appropriate part of the Particle Data Group's compilation) into your question? The preference for the highest-mass decay state suggests there's an additional symmetry which you haven't accounted for, probably to do with the difference between a $B$ and a $B^*$.